# UITableView SectionIndexTitle Custom View

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I've googled for about 2 days about my problem already. But I couldn't find any solution that matches with my problem. My problem is I want to make a custom SectionIndexTitle for UITableView like an image below. Please recommend me any library or concept to do it. Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create an alphabetic index there is method in UITableViewDelegate that supports it out of the box.

You'll need to define your sections and then use UILocalized​Indexed​Collation to index them.

```
 let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.currentCollation()
    as UILocalizedIndexedCollation

// table sections
var sections: [Section] {
    if self._sections != nil {
        return self._sections!
    }

    // create objects from your datasource
    var objects: [Object] = names.map { objectAttribute in
        var object = Object(objectAttribute: objectAttribute)
        object.section = self.collation.sectionForObject(object, collationStringSelector: objectAttribute)
        return object
    }

    // create empty sections
    var sections = [Section]()
    for i in 0..<self.collation.sectionIndexTitles.count {
        sections.append(Section())
    }

override func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView)
    -> [AnyObject] {
    return self.collation.sectionIndexTitles
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String,
    atIndex index: Int)
    -> Int {
    return self.collation.sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex(index)
}
```

To read more about [UILocalized​Indexed​Collation](http://nshipster.com/uilocalizedindexedcollation/)